# Problems loading WPF image in code, where am i going wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have an image in my xaml as so:

```
<Image Name="TotalFloors" Width="98" Source="../Images/FloorOne.png" Margin="0 0 0 10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

This is loading fine, however everything i have tried to get this image change in code has resulted in nothing being displayed.

I tried a MessageBox.Show(TotalFloors.Source.ToString()); and it returned:

pack://application:,,,/MyClient;component/Images/FloorOne.png

Which then prompted me to use this code:

```
        private void GetFloorImg()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(TotalFloors.Source.ToString());
        BitmapImage floorImage = new BitmapImage();
        Uri uriSource;
        switch (App.selectedBuilding.Floors)
        {
            case 1:
                uriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyClient;component/Images/FloorOne.png", UriKind.Absolute);
                break;
            case 2:
                uriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyClient;component/Images/FloorTwo.png", UriKind.Absolute);
                break;
            case 3:
                uriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyClient;component/Images/FloorThree.png", UriKind.Absolute);
                break;
            default :
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        floorImage.UriSource = uriSource;
        TotalFloors.Source = floorImage;

    }
```

However this is not working either.
The images are all set to resource in the folder. And a breakpoint shows that my code is being hit.

Any Ideas?
TIA, Kohan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
floorImage.UriSource = uriSource;
TotalFloors.Source = floorImage;
```

instead use this:

```
TotalFloors.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
```

Comment: This works great, im not quite sure what the difference between (BitmapImage floorImage = new BitmapImage(); floorImage.UriSource = uriSource;) and (new BitmapImage(uriSource);) They seem the same to me. Could you tell me what's different please?

Comment: The UriSource property must be set between calls to BeginInit and EndInit (see my answer). This constructor does exactly that

Answer (score 2):

Just a little modification to your code :

```
private void GetFloorImg()
{
    MessageBox.Show(TotalFloors.Source.ToString());
    BitmapImage floorImage = new BitmapImage();
    Uri uriSource;
    switch (App.selectedBuilding.Floors)
    {
        case 1:
            uriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyClient;component/Images/FloorOne.png", UriKind.Absolute);
            break;
        case 2:
            uriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyClient;component/Images/FloorTwo.png", UriKind.Absolute);
            break;
        case 3:
            uriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyClient;component/Images/FloorThree.png", UriKind.Absolute);
            break;
        default :
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    floorImage.BeginInit();
    floorImage.UriSource = uriSource;
    floorImage.EndInit();
    TotalFloors.Source = floorImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void GetFloorImg()
{
    string logoFileLocation = "pack://application:,,,/MyClient;component/Images/";

    switch (App.selectedBuilding.Floors)
    {
        case 1:
            logoFileLocation += "FloorOne.png";
            break;
        case 2:
            logoFileLocation += "FloorTwo.png";
            break;
        case 3:
            logoFileLocation += "FloorThree.png";
            break;
        default :
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    TotalFloors.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(logoFileLocation, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

PS: Build Action for Images should be "Resource" and after adding or modifying a resource, you must rebuild the solution. You know the first part (which you have written in the question) and I think you also know the second, but just in case.